How to get global IPv6 address of the current machine?
I a bash script, I want to obtain the global IPv6 address of my machine for a given network adapter (on my case 'ens18').
To get started, I issued the following command:
ip -6 addr

This gives me the followig output, which contains the address I'm looking for:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens18: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 fd00::3170:4ff:eff4:a4ab/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 6736sec preferred_lft 3136sec
    inet6 2a02:8070:2982:4300:3170:4ff:eff4:a4ab/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 6736sec preferred_lft 3136sec
    inet6 af60::3170:4ff:eff4:a4ab/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: br-7ac197bd041e: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP 
    inet6 af60::42:80ff:fe52:3481/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP 
    inet6 af60::42:6eff:fecf:5e6/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: veth074f8b0@if5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP 
    inet6 af60::7073:40ff:fe59:aad0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: vethe85ed67@if7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP 
    inet6 af60::5c09:65ff:fe34:34f4/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

So the global IPv6 address is "2a02:8070:2982:4300:3170:4ff:eff4:a4ab".
How can retrieve this value reliably from my bash script?

I would start with
ip -6 addr ls -deprecated primary dev ens18 scope global | awk '/inet6/{print $2}'

where

dev ens18 tell ip to query only for ens18
-deprecated (to be put after ls or show) filter out temporary outgoing IP
primary select primary (e.g. first IP given to interface)
scope global print only global adress (won't print link level address like fe80:: )
/inet6/ tell awk to filter line with inet6
{ print $2} print value

Note that ipv6 like fe80::  are local address (thoses are filtered out by scope global flag).

a more XXI-th century solution would be
ip --json addr ${OTHER_ARGS} |
  jq -r '.[].addr_info[] |
         select(.scope == "global") |
         select(.family == "inet6") |
         .local'

(with ${OTHER_ARGS} from awk's solution above)

thanks to @GeraldSchneider for providing XXI century method, I fold for readability.

To add a clarification I forgot yesterday: fdXX:: are global scope, not site scope. Site-scoped addresses used to be fec0::, but they gave up on whole concept of "site-local", so the fdXX:: "ULA" addresses used nowadays are global scope (just like 192.168.x in IPv4) and won't be filtered out like this.

I would say that instead of parsing ip output or relying on tools like js (which needs to be installed), you may start off the hostname -I output which simply presents a list of all IP addresses assigned to the machine. Like this:
for i in `hostname -I`; do if echo ${i} | grep -qv \\. ; then echo ${i}; break; fi done

This will show the first IPv6 address appeared in the list, even if it's link-local or site-local. You can grep them away too:
for i in `hostname -I`; do if echo ${i} | grep -qvP "\.|^fe80:|^fd00:" ; then echo ${i}; break; fi done


This meanwhile relies on the Debian variant of hostname – there's no -I option in the inetutils variant that a few other distributions use. (It has -i but that only resolves the system hostname, which may be set to resolve to only 127.0.0.1.)

Well... that's right. I overlooked that. Thank you for pointing it out!

@grawity just discovered that no, not only Debian, but Oracle Linux 7 and 8 has -I option too. And it works the same way, i.e. the command above works perfectly on OL8. So I'd expect the same behavior at least from corresponding RHEL/CentOS/Rocky/Alma/whatever versions.
